# Qual é origem da língua portuguesa?

Tags: origem-histórica, origem

Andei pesquisando sobre a origem da língua portuguesa e encontrei alguns links interessantes que explicam um pouco do assunto.

Nas referências fala-se que o Português vem do Latim vulgar.

Gostaria de saber se isso é verdade e se as histórias sobre a origem do português estão corretas.

Alguém com conhecimento no assunto pode agregar mais informações além das referências?

#### Referências:

- https://www.estudopratico.com.br/a-origem-da-lingua-portuguesa/
- http://tecciencia.ufba.br/aula-de-portugues-2012/aula-de-portugues-2012/a-origem-da-lingua-portuguesa

Comment: Com efeito, a língua portuguesa provém do Latim, especialmente o vulgar. Todo consenso historiográfico sobre o português, assim como as demais línguas populares, pode ser facilmente encontrado na internet.

Comment: William, você pode referenciar um bom link de uma fonte confiável?

Comment: https://fenix.letras.ulisboa.pt/courses/hlp-3-283923108070462/sumarios?p=10 Tem um monte de livros na bibliografia. Só que vai ser preciso comprar os livros ou ir a uma biblioteca.

Comment: @Lambie desculpe não responder, acabei esquecendo desse tópico, muito obrigado por compartilhar, esse link contém informações interessantes.

Answer (score 3):

O português, assim como outras línguas românicas como espanhol e italiano, vieram do Latim vulgar.

Latim vulgar é a variante do latim falada por pessoas comuns, que nunca estudaram (lembrando que na época, quase 90% da população era analfabeta), principalmente em áreas longe de Roma. Quando os romanos invadiram a região onde Portugal veio a se formar, eles introduziram a língua latina lá. Tinha o latim "culto" usado pelo governo e o latim coloquial (latim vulgar) usado pelo povo.

Com o passar do tempo, línguas tendem a mudar e ficar diferente em diversas regiões, principalmente se elas forem isoladas e não tiver uma tradição literária. Por isso existem sotaques e variantes regionais. Para exemplificar, as diferenças entre português brasileiro e o de Portugal surgiram com o passar de mais de 200 anos. O Espanhol é parecido com o Português por terem a mesma origem e a proximidade geográfica, mas são quase mil anos de distanciamento e ficaram diferentes o suficiente para serem duas línguas distintas. Quanto mais longe de Portugal, mais diferente é a língua românica.

E muitas coisas influenciaram a língua local durante os séculos. Desde o início, já havia povos na península Ibérica antes da chegada dos romanos e isso já começou a influenciar o Latim que chegou lá. Depois a península Ibérica foi invadida por tribos germânicas e por árabes, antes da fundação de Portugal, e isso introduziu mais diferenças na língua da região. No Brasil, a língua foi influenciada pelos povos locais (Tupis, Guaranis, etc) e por povos africanos trazidos como escravos. Imigrantes italianos, japoneses, alemães, poloneses e sírio-libaneses também tiveram influência e contribuíram para diversidade regional brasileira.

Comment: Acredito exagerada a importância dos idiomas tupi-guaranis e de imigrantes (incluso africanos) em sua resposta. A variante brasileira em língua escrita culta difere em pouco da portuguesa; na verdade, o pt-br é mais similar ao português arcaico (sec. XVI) do que o pt-pt.

Answer (score 0):

A lingua Portuguesa moderna não possui um único ponto de origem, ela provém de várias origens, como: Latin, Galego e até mesmo o Árabe (como exemplo, não exclusivo, vide palavras com prefixo "al", como almanaque, alfarrábio).

Uma boa fonte de informações que podem lhe ajudar como qual caminho seguir em sua pesquisa é o podcast "SciCast #248: A História da Língua Portuguesa" https://castbox.fm/x/F-1G. Este podcast conta com presenças de um Linguista, um Internacionalista e um Historiador.

No mesmo site, há referencias bibliográficas que você também pode fazer uso.

Comment: 'Al' no caso seria artigo mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Latin arcaico
Sefaradi
Espanhol antigo
Africano
Euskadi
Inglesismos
Fracesismos.
Uma dos mais belos idiomas.
Tāo belo, que Gabriela Mistral(Lucila Godoy Alcayaga, premio Nobel de literatura , 1945, empresta a palavra, para um dos seus poemas. Chilena)
Um chileno enamorado do Brasil.